# Permission denied error while using sudo or su?

Tags: permissions, sudo

I'm trying to fix my screen brightness problem, and I have checked some answers given on this site.
I found out that I may have to use some command like this:

```
ls -la /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/ > lslabacklight
```

The problem is, while running this either with `sudo` or entered as super user `su`, I get an error saying permission is denied.

```
sudo ls -la /sys/calss/backlight/intel_backlight/ > lslbacklight
bash: lslbacklight: Permission denied
```

How do I make it work? I got the idea of doing this from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight).

Comment: Which directory are you in? Also, does this file already exist? If yes, who owns it?

Comment: yes it exists and root owns it. i tried it using root user (su) but had the same error

Comment: Are you actually in an rooted shell or are you using sudo? Does it work with `sudo ls -la /sys/calss/backlight/intel_backlight/ | sudo tee lslbacklight`?

Comment: i get an access denied for tee and No such file for ls. but i have confirmed and checked that i have intel_backlight

Comment: My bad, I mistyped the path in my comment (`calss` instead of `class`). As for the other problem, what does `ls -l lslbacklight` print?

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root